# Flicker free Form behavior on resize - keep from redrawing

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make form flicker free on resize. I used the recommended approach of sending `WM_SETREDRAW`:

```
protected override void OnResizeBegin(EventArgs e)
{
  //LockWindowUpdate(this.Handle);
  SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, false, 0);
  base.OnResizeBegin(e);
}

protected override void OnResizeEnd(EventArgs e)
{
  base.OnResizeEnd(e);
  SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, true, 0);
  //LockWindowUpdate(IntPtr.Zero);
}

private const int WM_SETREDRAW = 11;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool LockWindowUpdate(IntPtr windowHandle);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 wMsg, bool wParam, Int32 lParam);
```

But it doesn't achieve what I want. When I expand the form, the extra size becomes black area, which gets redrawn when I end resize:

[Image expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAgxx.png)

Similarly, when I shrink the form, its contents get clipped and recalculates after I end resize:

[Image shrunk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNGpb.png)

I would like to prevent these intermediate behaviors, for example only redraw a rectangle with form new size while doing resizing, but other than that, form area should be unchanged until I end resize - similar behavior is present when moving splitter in SplitContainer control.

Is there a way to do this for Form in WinForms?

Comment: It is not a "recommended approach".  But it did what you asked it to do, no redraw so you are seeing the back of the monitor.

Comment: It does not do what I want. When I use SplitContainer control for comparison, neither of its inner panels is actually resized until I end resizing. There is no black background or clipping in between. I need similar behavior for Form.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: That doesn't help me solve my issue unfortunately.

Comment: Before going down that road you did turn in DoubleBuffering, right? (which is the recommended way to avoid flicker.)

Comment: I tried      `this.DoubleBuffered = true;` as well as
      `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);`, neither eliminate flickering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to resolve this.

Solution involves overriding WndProc to manually set SPI_SETDRAGFULLWINDOWS to 0, then reset when done resizing. Also, CreateParams were overridden for the form to set flag WS_EX_COMPOSITED. WM_SETREDRAW is also sent on beginning and ending resizing. Combining those three methods gave me result I wanted.